# What is the namespace for Wpf controls in vb.net?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am writing a class library for a WPF VB.NET application and I am trying to get access to the namespace where the classes for various wpf controls are located. What namespace are wpf controls located in? I normally would just google such a question, but i couldnt find anything via that avenue.

Comment: That's strange. The first result I get when I google 'wpf controls namespace' is [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655881%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which says that WPF controls are in the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace.

Comment: According to Visual Studio 2015, there is no such thing as `System.Windows.Controls` it only gives me `System.Windows.Markup` and `System.Windows.Input`. I also tried imports and it still didn't give me any more options

Comment: Do you have reference to PresentationFramework dll ?, only then you can find the namespace.

Comment: If this is in a Class Library project, you will be missing the references for the libraries that contain the WPF controls and will need to add the references to your project (right-click on references in Solution Explorer).

Comment: @Aang what the person above said is right, and I'd like to add to it a question, why don't you use WPF User Control Library if you need to access the controls? that way you will have all you need there, you can then even add UserControls etc easly to this type of project

Comment: @adminSoftDK Oh. I am new to WPF so I was unaware that was a thing. Thank you very much for the advice

Comment: @Aang if that solved your problem, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a WPF User Control Library you will have all you need there, you can then even add UserControls etc easly to this type of project.